# как растянуть div во всю ширину в div c overflow-x: scroll

Tags: прокрутка

как растянуть div во всю ширину в div c overflow-x: scroll

html:

```
<div class="p1">
  <p>204204204200420424204204204420420420420420420000420</p>
  <div class="p2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.p1 {width:300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;  overflow-x: scroll;}
.p2 {height: 30px; background: #902457;  display: block;}
```

то же самое тут: http://jsfiddle.net/2ghb3ahc/12/

в итоге видно что малиновый блок не растягивается на всю ширину внутри div, а принимает ширину родителя, как его растянуть на всю ширину? не прибегая к wight со значениями px так как длинна текста будет меняться, а wight 100% не помогает

Comment: <div class="p2">  тоже должен двигаться вместе с текстом .p2 {position:fixed;} не вариант в моем случае

Comment: через css не нашел как сделать, тока через  jquery , вдруг кому то понадобится

document.querySelector(".p2").style.width = document.querySelector(".p1").scrollWidth + "px";

Answer (score 2):

можно попробывать с кастылем...:

```css
.p1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.p2 {
  position:fixed;
  height: 30px;
  background: #902457;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p1">
  <p>204204204200420424204204204420420420420420420000420 </p>
  <div class="p2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не то чуть, див тоже должен двигаться вместе с текстом, в нем тоже инфа будет, он не просто для цвета

*просто упростил код по минимуму для быстрого понимания

Comment: @Леха какого эффекта вы хотите добиться? тескст изначально задается или динамически?